# Laravel collection: flatten method ignored

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Possibly an obvious one, but here it is:
After dd'ing a query result, I have:

```
$items = DB::table('my_table')->get(['id']);
dd($items);
```

Which results in:

```
Collection {#228 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#227 ▼
      +"id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, when I try to flatten it, it ignores me:

```
dd($items->flatten());
```

Resulting in:

```
Collection {#209 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#227 ▼
      +"id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Shouldn't I receive something like the flattened version of the collection?
How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to call `$items->flatten()->all();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check it like

```
$flattened = $items->flatten();

dd($flattened->all());

// or dd($items->flatten()->all());
```

Source from [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-flatten).

If you want to fetch id and completely flatten then use

```
$items = DB::table('my_table')->pluck('id');
dd($items);
```

Here is the [pluck link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck).

Comment: Doing that results in: `array:1 [▼
  0 => {#227 ▼
    +"id": 2
  }
]`

Shouldn't it be something like `array:1 [▼
  0 => 2
]` ??

Comment: Try this then `$items->flatten(1)->values()->all();`

Comment: Same result with that. I want to get rid of `id` key, i.e., completely flatten it

Comment: `$items = DB::table('my_table')->pluck('id');` Change your query to this and directly `dd($items);`

Comment: Not the smartest solution, but it works for me. Thanks.